# Gracefully handling a site update

Tags: downtime

I'm in the process of changing things on one of my sites. As I don't really have a staging environment I'm planning to take the site offline for about a couple of hours.

How do I handle this gracefully so that if Google visits I don't get penalized?

Comment: Is there a CMS in place? Many of them have a plugin/module/etc. that lets you throw together a quick "maintenance mode" screen. Actually taking the site **down** isn't the best idea, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Pending my CMS question above, there are ways to redirect all traffic to a maintenance page, so that it doesn't look like your site's dead. (It seems like you're thinking of actually taking the site down meanwhile.) Here's a [method with htaccess](http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/05/19/htaccess-redirect-maintenance-page-site-updates/), assuming you're on an Apache server.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest throwing a 302 and sending users and bots to a maintenance page. I think that might be good enough. Would have expected that Google to come up with some protocol to handle such situations.